# Android autohide feature interferes with my TabHost

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have a test app using TabHost on an Android 4.x. It works ok, except that the TABS are hidden behind the title stuff (that should autohide).
If I enable autohide it's not good either, because even if I see that the title is hiding and the TABS are directly accessible... if I try to click on a TAB, then the titlebar comes down overlapping the TABS and preventing me from clicking on my TAB.

What should I do?
Here is my layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0099cc"
    tools:context="ro.whatever.myapp.testtabhost.app.main">


    <TabHost
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</FrameLayout>
```

So after I create the activity for this layout... I cannot click on the TABS that I can see on top of the screen because the titl-bar drops down and takes the click on itself ...

This is annoying.
How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing this in onCreate of the Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); // this thing hides the title bar so I can access the TabHost
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

For whom it may concern ;)